# What is the best way to integrate/call a MySQL database into a front-end web application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql, database

I am designing and building a MySQL relational database on a local server and also building a front-end using HTML/CSS/Javascript. I need a way to connect these two (they'll be on the same server), and call and display tables from the MySQL database onto the front-end web-app.

Can javascript do this? I've looked up a few answers on here and it seems like about 5 years ago the answer was no. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use Node.js on the server side.

Comment: Also there are js libs that you can use on your website. But this is not secure, unless you are the only user who visits the page.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is creating an HTTP interface to your MySQL database.

If you are comfortable using Javascript, you can make one with [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/), using, for example [Expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) and [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/)

You can find very good tutorials on the web. [This one for example](https://medium.com/valtech-ch/setup-a-rest-api-with-sequelize-and-express-js-fae06d08c0a7)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am looking for. I'll start learning.

Answer (score 0):

You'll always need a server to connect your database to a front-end application. There are some SaaS products that simplify the relationship between the server and DB like Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

If you want to use MySQL, you'll need a server to provide an API: popular interfaces are REST, SOAP, or GQL.

If you want to write your server with Javascript, Express is a very common and approachable solution: https://expressjs.com/

Comment: That is not true. There are web based JS libs. But you will expose your credentials if you inspect element.

Comment: @DalexHD If credentials must be exposed they are useless for any real application.

Comment: If it's a personal website, where you are the only user who have access, you can do it. Of course, it's not recommended.

Comment: @DalexHD, that's fair. Are there other notable exceptions? Such as a site running locally, or maybe an Electron app.

Comment: Yeap, locally and electron apps could make this if they are used by only the same person. Have you looked chorme, Firefox... Db integrated engine? You can have a database on your storage. Anyways, I recommend you to use firebase at your case. 

Comment: Is your application server less? Use firebase. Does your  app work with backend server? Use nodejs to achieve this.

Comment: We'll have a dedicated server and it'll be hosted locally. I'll have full admin access to the database, but I want to build a front-end for other employees to access only what they need.